# How to Choose Formattype for Matlab's saveas with Big Matrices?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I am trying to increase the input matrix size by 10^3 and found out that Matlab's saveas command does not work anymore with my current setting

```
saveas(imgRGB, filenamePng)
```

Error

```
217     saveas(imgRGB, filenamePng);
Error using saveas (line 58)
Invalid handle.

Error in masi (line 217)
    saveas(imgRGB, filenamePng);

 function saveas( h, name, format )
 ↑
Error: Function definitions are not permitted in this context.
```

I can plot the image correctly still by `imshow(imgRGB)` so it indicates something is wrong with `saveas` itself and its settings. 
I investigated the memory and found that this part is giving the error in the command `saveas` on the line 57

```
if ~all(ishandle(h))
    error('MATLAB:saveas:invalidHandle','%s',...
        getString(message('MATLAB:saveas:invalidHandle')))
end
```

I do not understand the behaviour because it is dependent on the size of the matrix you give to the command. 
I think the only way to avoid it is to explicitly define the third parameter like

```
saveas(imgRGB, filenamePng, formattype)
```

I do unsuccessfully `saveas(imgRGB, filenamePng, 'png')` giving the output

```
217     saveas(imgRGB, filenamePng, 'png');
Error using saveas (line 58)
Invalid handle.

Error in masi (line 217)
    saveas(imgRGB, filenamePng, 'png');
```

I think I may need to change the output format from .png to .eps (EPS Level 3 Black and White) which may be better suitable for scientific computation, since I only need about 1024 gray colors.
However, doing `..., 'eps')` gives the same error as with last command.

### Code

```
dpi=100;
diffTime = timeEndSeconds - timeStartSeconds; 
N=361; 
unitsPerInches = [0 0 15 15];

hFig=figure('Visible', 'off', ...
    'Units', 'inches', 'Position', unitsPerInches);

time=linspace(timeStartSeconds, timeEndSeconds, diffTime*N);
imagesc(time, potential, matrix); 
set(gca, ...
    'color','none', ... % no background
    'position', unitsPerInches*dpi^1,'units','normalized' ... 
    ); 
colormap(gray); % here many gray varieties
imgRGB = print(hFig, '-RGBImage', strcat('-r', num2str(dpi))); 
saveas(imgRGB, filenamePng, 'eps');
```

---

How can you set formattype and saveas for a big matrix in Matlab?

Comment: How did you get `imgRGB`? becuase it needs to be a handle. Is it a hanlde, or an image?

Comment: Can you just post a MCVE? We shouldn't need to ask for this every time...

Comment: Thanks. Now it is clear what you do wrong. As I said, the fisrt inout of saveas needs to be a figure handle, and you are using an image. Use `imwritte` for that.

Comment: Unfortunately thats your problem! Not wanting to use an specific function because yes. However, if you need to use it, Im gonna suggest you read again **all my comments and answer, including the documentation** and give saveas a figure handle as input.

Comment: @AnderBiguri You are right!

Comment: @Masi can you take a step back from all of these posts and tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish? I think that we are way off track and there is likely a *much* better way of accomplishing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of saving images in Matlab.

1. You have a RGB array (dimensions: imageHeight*imageWidth*3), and
   you write it to disk with `imwrite(rgbImage,fileName)`,
2. You plot it in a figure (`imshow`, `imagesc`) and then print the figure
   to file (`saveas(figureHandle, fileName)`, where `figureHandle` is a
   scalar). Neither way should be limited by variable size.

Comment: @Masi Can you then shown us how in your question? Don't give sparse information in comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you [read the documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html?refresh=true), it is clear that if you call `saveas` with 2 inputs it:

> `saveas(fig,filename)` saves the figure or Simulink® block diagram
>   specified by fig to file filename.

Thus, if you are saving Simulink blocks, call it with 2 arguments, else with 3.